# Docker : class path resource cannot be resolved for Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, classpath

In my Spring Boot app, I read some csv file located in `resources\data` folder and I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.2-openjdk-17-slim AS builder

# add pom.xml and source code
ADD ./pom.xml pom.xml
ADD ./src src/

# package jar
RUN mvn clean install

# Second stage: minimal runtime environment
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

# copy jar from the first stage
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY --from=builder ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

When I run the app after building the container, I get the following error:

> "class path resource [data/employees.csv] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/data/employees.csv"

I think I need to add the `resources\data` folder to my container. So, how can I do this? What is the most proper way?

Note: I also tried to fix the problem using `new ClassPathResource(filename).getInputStream()`, but it did not make any sense and still the same problem.

Comment: As you can see in the error, it's trying to load the file from `classes` classpath. You can add the file to the container doing `ADD src/resources/data/employees.csv /folder/` and in the code use the same path

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are 3 csv files to be read and in this case, can I copy the whole folder content via `ADD src/resources/data /data/` in the Dockerfile? As I mentioned, I am using `resources\data` in my code and probably no need to change it. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, that should solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the command is true? The path in the project is `src\main\resources\data` and the error message shows `jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/data/employees.csv` now when I try with `ADD ./src/main/resources/data /data/`. So, is that true? Because still getting error :(

Comment: You gotta adjust your code to read from the new path `/data`

Comment: My code is already read form data in the resources folder. Could you please explain a little bit more? I am confused a little bit.

Comment: Right. You are putting your files under `/data` in the container. You code is reading from the classpath. Make your code read from `/data` instead from the classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Finally I solved the problem by using `resource.getInputStream()`.

Comment: Do you have any idea for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597445/dockerfile-cannot-run-maven-command-during-build ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597445/dockerfile-cannot-run-mvn-clean-install-during-building-docker-image

Comment: But what's your question? As it says there in that answer, everything works as expected

Comment: Could you check this pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597445/dockerfile-bin-sh-1-mvnw-not-found-error